# Get coroutine scope reference inside anonymous inner class

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

- I am using `lifecycleScope` to make a simple api call inside a fragment to get some data and store it in `Room database`.
- As soon as I get a response inside *Anonymous Inner Class* I cannot get a reference of `CoroutineScope` to call a suspension method because of *Anonymous Inner Class*. How can I get reference of the current `CoroutineScope`?

Demo:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    SomeClass(context).getDataFromApi( object : CallBackResult<Any> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: Any) {
           saveToLocal()   // I have to call a suspension function from here
        }
    })   
}

suspend fun saveToLocal() {
     //save some data
}
```

Note: **I am not following MVVM Pattern but MVC.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make use of `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to turn your blocking API call into a suspending function:

```
suspend fun getDataFromApi(context: Context): Any = suspendCancellableCoroutine { continuation ->
    SomeClass(context).getDataFromApi( object : CallBackResult<Any> {
        override fun onSuccess(result: Any) {
            continuation.resume(result)
        }
    })
}
```

And you can call it like this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val result = getDataFromApi(context) //Here you get your API call result to use it wherever you need
    saveToLocal()
}
```

Comment: Can we use async & await approach for the same?

Comment: @SumitShukla `suspendCancellableCoroutine` is meant to be like a "wrapper" for blocking API calls to turn them into suspending functions. There's no need to use `async` & `await` since by calling `continuation.resume(...)` it already returns the result as soon as the API responds. If you're asking if you can call the suspending function inside an `async` body to work with its result and return something else then sure, that's totally right.

Comment: Can I use launch{} directly inside onSuccess? Is it discouraged?

Comment: @SumitShukla I wouldn't do it that way for 2 reasons: 1- I would be doing more than one thing inside the function which complicates things up. 2- Testing it would be a pain. To me that's discouraging enough.